# How can I combine a number of columns value together using loop condition in R

Tags: r

Now I have a matrix like below and I cannot access specific column but to use matrixname[,3] to access

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    8    2   10    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[2,]   10    2    8   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[3,]    8    6    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,]    1    3   10    8   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]    4    6    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[6,]    8    2   10    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[7,]    1    8    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[8,]    2    6    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

I'm using a loop when the i value of the loop is 2, I need to merge the column one and column two value like 8,2 10,2. When my loop i is 3, I will have to merge column 1 to column 3 like 8,2,10.

Or is there any better way to merge the column value easily? Later I need to compare the merge value 8,2 with another matrix to check whether it exist or not.

I have another matrix like this formed using

> `df1 <- cSplit(data.frame(a = gsub('<-', '', trans$V1)), 'a', ' ','wide') 
>   aw <- cbind(df1, rules[,-1])`

```
     a_1 a_2 a_3 V2       V3
 1:  10   8   3  7 0.318182
 2:   3   8  10  7 0.437500
 3:   8   3  10  7 1.000000
 4:   3   8  NA 22 0.448980
 5:   8   3  NA 22 0.846154
 6:   9   8  10  7 0.437500
```

I use `subset(aw,is.na(a_3))` to remove row that are NA, then I want to merge a_2 and a_3 using loop as well because I might have a_4 or a_5.
Expected Ouput:

```
    a_1  a_2,a_3  V2       V3
 1:  10   8,3     7 0.318182
 2:   3   8,10    7 0.437500
 3:   8   3,10    7 1.000000
 4:   3   8,NA   22 0.448980
 5:   8   3,NA   22 0.846154
 6:   9   8,10    7 0.437500
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the 'aw' input

Comment: @akrun I already edit it, hope it help. I just need to be able to combine the value together from that two column, now I cannot used the method before to do it.

Comment: You need to use `data.table` methods for that. i.e. `aw[, a_2_a_3 := paste(a_2, a_3, sep=",")][, c('a_2', 'a_3') := NULL][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use a `for` loop (in that case, create an object to store the output) or use one of the `apply` family functions i.e. `sapply/lapply`.  Loop over the sequence of columns in this case, we are using only the first 3 columns.  subset the `matrix`, `paste` the rows and assign the output to the 'lst' already created.

```
lst <- vector("list", 3);
for(i in seq_along(lst)){
 lst[[i]] <- do.call(paste, 
      c(as.data.frame(m1[, 1:i, drop=FALSE]), list(sep=",")))
}

lst
#[[1]]
#[1] "8"  "10" "8"  "1"  "4"  "8"  "1"  "2" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "8,2"  "10,2" "8,6"  "1,3"  "4,6"  "8,2"  "1,8"  "2,6" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "8,2,10" "10,2,8" "8,6,9"  "1,3,10" "4,6,9"  "8,2,10" "1,8,3"  "2,6,4"
```

If we need it as a `matrix`, either `rbind` or `cbind` the output of the `list`

```
do.call(cbind, lst)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know can write in this way do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(m1[, 1:i, drop=FALSE]), list(sep=","))

Comment: @Alex, If there are many columns, then to `paste` all the columns, `do.call` can be used on a `data.frame`.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question above, just now I try to used the method you taught me to merge the second matrix above, but it cannot work because I cannot retrieve single column using matrix[,2].

Comment: @Alex the `cSpit` output is a data.table.  I am not sure why you are calling it as matrix.